# InnoDB: Error (Duplicate key) writing word node to FTS auxiliary index table. From myServerName.err

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have Mysql server running on windows server 2012 since 2015, I found too much error messages in .err log file, messages are:
2019-06-12 09:26:39 2064  InnoDB: Error (Duplicate key) writing word node to FTS auxiliary index table.

And it still receiving errors daily.
What is that error meaning, can this error effect Mysql performance?
Note: mysql server is used from multiple projects.